# Jquery: подставить ссылку, там где есть http и/или доменная зона

Tags: jquery

Например пользователь ввел site.ru как строку, а ему сразу вывелось site.ru как ссылка

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links — пойдет?

Comment: не очень, не хотел бы на сервере это делать

Comment: так это на клиенте :] Вот пример использования — http://jsfiddle.net/6Qjzs/

Comment: оу, тупанул) прошу прощения)

Comment: мне тоже интересна эта тема